# select dict keys and values from a defaultdict

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

If i have a defaultdict that looks like:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'trust:team_member': ['partners'], 'contacts': ['first_names\', \'last_names\']", "[\'names']})
```

How do i select the dict? I have tried:

```
print(dd.items())

dict_items([('trust:team_member', ['partners']), ('contacts', ['first_names\', \'last_names\']", "[\'popular_names_2010_2020'])])
```

essentially i need this to look like:

```
example_dict ={'trust:team_member': ['partners'], 'contacts': ['first_names', 'last_names', 'names'}
```

Comment: What's the output of `print(dd['contacts'][0])`? Looking at your post, it looks like the list contains just one string and not three.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just turn it into a `dict`:

```
>>> dict(dd)
{'trust:team_member': ['partners'], 'contacts': ['first_names', 'last_names', 'names'}
```

If you're used to any other languages it's similar to typecasting

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a dict_items object, and you can iterate over it. So I think what you could do is something like this,

```
example_dict = {}

for i in dd.items():
    example_dict[i[0]] = i[1]
```

I think that works(correct me if I'm wrong, I didn't actually run this code)